# Create Hierarchical Arraylist at Runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am using the mx:tree control and need to populate the tree nodes dynamically at run time. Here is what I have:

```
var ac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

ac.addItem({ item: "Parent Item", group: "Group 1"});
ac.addItem( { item: "Parent Item", group: "Group 2" } );

var childac:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

childac.addItem({ item: "Child Item", group: "Group 1"});

//not sure how to add the childac to the ac

trvMain.dataProvider = ac;
```

How do I append the child array collection to the parent array collections so that the treeview show the he hierarchical view correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This is off the of my head by here goes.  If you are using a Tree, your model has to implement [ITreeDataDescriptor2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/treeClasses/ITreeDataDescriptor2.html).  Right now, it seems like you have just a regular object which I don't think is going to work.  If I were solving this problem, I would make a model Wrapper/Adapter class which implement and provide the functionality specified in ITreeDataDescriptor2.